# Replace HTML that has data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, replace

Im using Tiny MCE along a character count plugin. For the most part it works but it has one flaw in that it counts all the following characters when you hit the return key.

```
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
```

But when this is saved into the database it saves it as

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Which is completely fine. The problem lies on the validation, the input is restricted to 5000 characters and every return is counted as 30 character which throws of the validation count. i.e its saying there is over 5000 characters when in fact there is not.

The validation is done client side which checks the character count before the form can be submitted.

So far I have tried

```
var decodedStripped = decoded.replace('data-mce-bogus="1"', ' /').trim();
```

But it doesnt seem to strip the unnecessary data attribute.

This is purely needed for validation.

Answer (score 0):

I went another way with this. Instead of this

```
var decodedStripped = decoded.replace('data-mce-bogus="1"', ' /').trim();
```

I counted how many times the data-mce-bogus="1" sub-string occurred in the overall string. I then used this occurrence value along with the character count difference between `<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>` and `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

which lead to

```
    self.getCount = function () {
        var tx = editor.getContent({ format: 'raw' });

        var tcLength = tx.length;

        var noOfReturns = occurrences(tx, 'data-mce-bogus="1"', false);

        var cleanLength = tcLength - (17 * noOfReturns);

        return cleanLength;
    };
```

This allowed me to have the correct count so it validates correctly on the client side.